# RegEx for matching URLs with trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to write an expression for AngularJs. I need to use it inside an `ng-pattern` directive so to put a validation constraint to a form.

What I actually need is a regex for a URL in **https** that has always to end with a slash: <kbd>/</kbd>.

It would be nice if it ends more specifically in `/pre/last/`

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: can you show what have tried ?

Comment: @Emma It is not working. I don't need a rewrite expresion but something to use in angularjs ng-pattern

Comment: I would like something like this to be accepted: https 
 ://SOMETHING_HERE/pre/last/ and not be accepted if the last slash is missing like https ://SOMETHING_HERE/pre/last. But it has to have the /pre/last always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/CjdlRv/1) might help us to match `/pre/last/`. It creates two groups, in case we wish to call those groups, we can do so using `$2` for `/pre/last/` and `$1` for first the part of our URL (Please see the image).

```
 '/(.+)(\/pre\/last\/)/g'
```

We might not want to bound it with start (<kbd>^</kbd>) or end (<kbd>$</kbd>) anchors, and it might still does our desired matchings.

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) explains how we would do so in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help

`/.*\/pre\/last\/$/g`

what it basically match is any string that ends with `/pre/last/`

Comment: Not Working Omar.  I am sorry